# Pandas find matching sub-strings and split on them

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a pandas column that looks like this:

```
0                         LOT 8 BLK 32 MISSIONARY HEIGHTS 
1                          LTS 31-39 & PT 30, 15-22 LEWIS 
2                                          LT 2 DEPOT SUB
....
```

I want to extract out the lot number from this but sometimes they are spelled "LOT", "LTS" or "LT". And I want to extract out the lot number into a new column. So, for the example above, I would have:

```
         df['Lot']
0             8
1           31-39
2             2
```

How can I do this? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["Lot"] = df["Address"].str.extract(r'\b(?:LOT|LTS?) (\d+(?:-\d+)*)')
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/a4Vy0q/1) showing that the regex extraction logic is working.

To remove these lot values from the address, you may use `str.replace`:

```
df["Other"] = df["Address"].str.replace(r'\s*(?:LOT|LTS?) \d+(?:-\d+)*\s*', ' ').str.strip()
```

The final call to `strip()` is to remove dangling leading/trailing whitespace, which would occur for those addresses either starting or ending with a lot quantity.

Comment: Thanks, how can I reverse it too so I get the new address without the lot numbers?